# Rails: Polymorphic model, troubles with deletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

In my Rails movie database, I have now added a "Tag" model that can tag both movies and actors.
However I am not able to delete a tag that is used to tag either one of a movie or an actor (foreign_key constraint); when I call destroy on such a tag, Rails says:

```
Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`newmovie_development`.`taggings`, CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_e21d88485b` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`))
```

Movie (actor is exactly the same in this regard):

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_many :taggings, as: :taggable, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings
    ...
```

Tag:

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true

    has_many :taggings
    has_many :movies, through: :taggings, :source => 'taggable', :source_type => 'Movie'
    has_many :actors, through: :taggings, :source => 'taggable', :source_type => 'Actor'
end
```

Tagging:

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :tag
    belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: You're missing a test or set of repeatable steps which shows how you tried to delete it and an error message. Right now we just have a vary vague description of what you're doing.

Comment: just refined. The weird thing is that after restarting the server, I now CAN destroy actors and movies that have tags. So now only Tags cannot be destroyed... have added the error that occurred.

Comment: I think the issue is really that you tried to delete the row from tags instead of taggings.

Comment: righto - I think you are on the spot. I can't delete a tag directly - I first need to delete all associated taggings, and then I should be able to delete the tag. Polymorphic relations are making me scratchin my head!

Comment: This has very little to do with polymorphic associations - if you  use `has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy` it in your tag model it will remove all the associated taggings and thus the foreign key constraint violation. Just make sure you're not tripping yourself up on the semantics. To "remove a tag from an Actor or Movie" you want to delete a row from the taggings table. Not the tags table as that will remove the tag completely from all actors/movies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably a bit confused here. If you have a movie or actor that you want to be able to edit the tags for you can use the `tags_ids=` setter generated by `has_many :tags`.

```
<%= form_with(model: @actor) do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :tags_ids, 'Tags' %>
    <%= form.collection_checkboxes :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```
class ActorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_actor, except: [:new, :create, :index]

  def update
    if @actor.update(actor_params)
      redirect_to @actor, success: 'Actor updated' 
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_actor
    @actor = Actor.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  def actor_params
    params.require(:actor)
          .permit(:foo, :bar, tag_ids: [])
  end
end
```

This will automatically diff the array passed in the parameters against any existing rows in the taggings table and add/create rows accordingly.

If you want to create a button to "remove tags from a taggable" one by one (perhaps enhanced with ajax) you want to make sure you're actually deleting rows from the taggings table and not tags:

```
module Actors
  class TagsController < ApplicationController
    # DELETE /actors/1/tags/2
    def destroy
      @tagging = @actor.taggings.find_by!(tag_id: params[:id])
      @tagging.destroy
    end

    private

    def set_actor
      @actor = Actor.find(params[:actor_id])
    end
  end
end
```

If you do actually want to remove a tag completly from the entire system (the equivilent of burnination here on Stackoverflow) you need to setup the dependent option on the assocation so that the foreign key constraint is not violated:

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
  # ...
end
```

You should also make sure to add a unique index to ensure that you don't get duplicates in your taggings table:

```
add_index :taggings, [:tag_id, :taggable_id, :taggable_type], unique: true
```

And a validation:

```
class Tagging
  validates_uniqueness_of :tag_id, scope: [:taggable_id, :taggable_type]
end
```

Comment: thanks - this was exactly my problem. I was playing around with it yesterday and came to a similar conclusion - thanks for your exhaustive answer, very helpful!